# SQL Server 2016: Multiple Reporting Services Web Frontend

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016, datazen-server

Let me first describe the actual situation: We want to build a new SQL Server enviroment based on SQL Server 2016. AS you may know, in SQL Server 2016 the mobile reports from Datazen are integrated. So far so good. The Problem: In our current Enviroment, there is one internal Datazen Server and one external server. The external Datazen server exists only to read data from the internal one. So there is no direct Data Access (to Data Sources), the administration part is disabled and only the needed Services (to read from internal server) are installed.  We want to build that same archtiecture in SQL Server 2016 Reporting Services. Do you know any way to do that?

I thought the best solution was a second SQL Server with Reporting Services but only read access on the other SQL Server (didn't found any setting like this).

We don't want the internal server to be accessible over the web beacause of security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interesting question, but not sure i understand correctly ;) what do you mean with "the external datazen Server exists only to read data from the internal one"? How does this configuration look like? Do you have a sale out Deployment where the external Servers hosts "Web Application" and "Share Cache Instance" while internal Server hosts "Data Acquisition" and the same roles as the external Server?

In SSRS you can also Scale out web frontends, but all Servers will act as "data acquisition server" to stay in datazen terminology. Do you have security concerns with this topology? Whats the difference to have the data "read only" in DMZ or connect from DMZ/external Server to internal datasources? One Option would be to do a secure Application Publishing of internal SSRS Server with a Firewall like Microsoft ISA Server

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. The first part in your answer is the current setting of our Datazen enviroment. We think the easiest and most secure way is to redirect external access via proxy in the DMZ direct to our internal SSRS Server. So we don't have to worry about licencing and a complete new server either. What do you think about this possible solution? And thank you for your answer ;-)

Comment: >We think the easiest and most secure way is to redirect external >access via proxy in the DMZ direct to our internal SSRS Server.

I would do it this way! The only Thing you have to take care is that SSRS can handle the Requests from  SSRS.interal.domain and SSRS.external.domain . That should be configurable as host Header? in SSRS Config Mgr